# How can I maintain the insertion order while using a HashSet?

Tags: java, hashset

I need to maintain the recently inserted order in a set.

```java
Set<Intger> s = new HashSet<>();
s.add(1);
s.add(2);
s.add(3);
s.add(1);
print(s);
```

Upon using a LinkedHashSet() the order is (1,2,3). 
The order I want is (2,3,1). I would like an efficient way to combine properties of a set with that of a stack.

Comment: Short of implementing your own data structure, you can consider removing and re-inserting the element when an insertion returns `false`.

Comment: Tracking insertion order *is the point* of `LinkedHashSet`. Use it.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on this?

Answer (score 0):

It's so easy,just make a method to judge the set if it has the value need to be added,if is
remove it and then add it,if not just add it.

### This is the method.

```
package exercise.setInsertionOrder;

import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class SetInsertionOrder {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<Integer> s = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        /*s.add(1);
        s.add(2);
        s.add(3);
        s.add(1);*/
        addByJudgeValueIsAdded(s, 1);
        addByJudgeValueIsAdded(s, 2);
        addByJudgeValueIsAdded(s, 3);
        addByJudgeValueIsAdded(s, 1);
        System.out.println(s);
    }
    
    
    public static <T> void addByJudgeValueIsAdded(Set<T> set,T t){
        if(set.contains(t)){
            set.remove(t);
            set.add(t);
        }else{
            set.add(t);
        }
    }

}
```

---

This is the result.

> [2, 3, 1]

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
Set<Integer> s = new LinkedHashSet<>();
addToSet(1, s);
addToSet(2, s);
addToSet(3, s);
addToSet(1, s);
print(s);

void addToSet(Integer v, Set<Integer> s) {
    s.remove(v);
    s.add(v);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `LinkedHashSet` instead of `Hashset` for maintaining the insertion order.

```
Set<Integer> s = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>();
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Write a new class that implements Map interface. Use composition of LinkedHashSet.
2. Implement add so it checks for duplicates, removes them and readds them. Map directly rest of interface methods to the LinkedHashSet.
3. Write unit tests and give your code onto Codereview stack exchange.

Good luck.